# RestDoc of object that may contain another istance of the same class

Tags: spring, spring-restdocs

I have an object that can be simplified as follows:

```
{
    "myObject": {
        "values": [
            "a string value",
            123456, // a number value
            true, // a boolean value
            { // an object with an array of values
                "values": [
                    // same as before...
                    // it allows string/number/boolean/object
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so, I tried to write a `FieldDescriptor` for this object, but I don't know (and I can't find) how to document the fact that it may contains "infinite"  many object structured like itself.

---

**I am also fine with don't document the inside of the array part**, but if i try to do so I get this error:

> The following parts of the payload were not documented:

```
{
    "myObject":[
       {
          "values":[
             {
                "values":[ "pasta" ]
             },
             {
                "values":[ "pizza" ]
             },
             {
                "values":[ "mandolino" ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

#### My code

```java
public static List<FieldDescriptor> myObjectDescriptor = List.of(
    fieldWithPath("values").type(JsonFieldType.ARRAY).description("May be an array of 'STRING', 'BOOLEAN', 'NUMBER', or 'myObjectDescriptor'").optional(),
    fieldWithPath("values[].*").type(JsonFieldType.VARIES).description("you know...").optional(),
);
```

As I said before, I also tried to erase the second `fieldWithPath`, but the error persisted.

#### The YAML OpenAPI definition

```
myObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    values:
      items:
        type: object
        # I am not using 'oneOf' here because
        # of reasons not related with the question
        # oneOf:
        #   - type: integer
        #   - type: string
        #   - type: boolean
        #   - $ref: '#/myObject'
      type: array
      description: an array of 'STRING', 'BOOLEAN', 'NUMBER', or 'myObject'
```

EDIT: the YAML is correct, I can't have integers and strings in the same values array, I did it above for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Found a **disgustive** solution, that does not work for "infinite" many object, but at least it works for n layers...

```java
public static List<FieldDescriptor> myObjectDescriptor = List.of(
    fieldWithPath("values").type(JsonFieldType.ARRAY).description("May be an array of 'STRING', 'BOOLEAN', 'NUMBER', or 'myObjectDescriptor'").optional(),
    fieldWithPath("values[].*").type(JsonFieldType.VARIES).description("you know...").optional(),
    fieldWithPath("values[].values").type(JsonFieldType.ARRAY).description("don't look at me").optional(),
    fieldWithPath("values[].values[].*").type(JsonFieldType.VARIES).description("this is terrible").optional(),
    // ... and so on ...
);
```

I am open to better solutions...
otherwise I hope this **disgrace** can help someone